# Salesforce Error response for postman REST API with bearer token. Salesforce Edge is mentioned as cause for Error in response

Tags: rest, postman, salesforce, sfdc

Request:
Got the Bearer token from connected app using postman but query requesting for data is causing the error.
Is there any problem with Salesforce Edge enabled in Test sandbox.? As I could see the cause of the error with Salesforce Edge. Any inputs will be helpful

Request: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nnv8s.png)
[enter image description here][1]
Error Response: 400 Bad Request

GET http://xxxx--sit.sandbox.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v57/query?q=SELECT+name+FROM+account+limit+1
400
222 ms
GET /services/data/v57/query?q=SELECT+name+FROM+account+limit+1 HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer00D790000000OtR!AQYAQKktH7mrkpdBgJQ4_wxA3DKsvhr.Gq3E0hl0SF.hwMtqJpnZ6o4Vz4l16FTAWla4YVP_iWcdtFG8c7fpIP9mryrJBne8
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 2a26ac83-a5a9-4e62-b054-b69d3d95aff3
Cookie: BrowserId=FEoGIt19Ee6bF2PjASBKKw

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Sat, 09 Mar 2024 03:32:46 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: close
Server: sfdcedge
X-SFDC-Request-Id: 118b71687124a3c33d9e2da5887e90bb
X-SFDC-Edge-ERR: true
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'none'